# If statement conditions not met, code still executing

Tags: if-statement, vbscript

I'm writing a VBScript that searches the Active Directory for a computer object. If the object does not exist or exists and is in the correct OU, then it should run a separate script that creates/joins the computer to the AD.

```
ObjExist_CorrectOU_7 = Null
ObjExist_CorrectOU_10 = Null

If compare = True Then
  Win7_OU = "OU=DisallowRDP,OU=64Bit,OU=Win8"
  Win10_OU = "OU=DisallowRDP,OU=64Bit,OU=Win10"

  For x = 16 To 46
    If Asc(Mid(objRS.Fields("distinguishedName"), x, 1)) = Asc(Mid(Win7_OU, (x - 15), 1)) Then
      ObjExist_CorrectOU_7 = True
    Else
      ObjExist_CorrectOU_7 = False
    End If
  Next

  For y = 16 To 46
    If Asc(Mid(objRS.Fields("distinguishedName"), y, 1)) = Asc(Mid(Win10_OU, (y - 15), 1)) Then
      ObjExist_CorrectOU_10 = True
    Else
      ObjExist_CorrectOU_10 = False
    End If
  Next
End If

If ObjExist_CorrectOU_7 = True Then
  WScript.Echo "TRUE"
End If

Dim objShell

Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

filename = "C:\programdata\dell\kace\k2000_deployment_info.conf"
Win7_Deployment = "deployment_name=Windows 7 x64 with SP1, join AD"
Win10_Deployment = "deployment_name=Development Windows 10 (x64), join AD"

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set f = fso.OpenTextFile(filename)

Do While Not f.AtEndOfStream
  If ((f.ReadLine = Win7_Deployment) Or ((f.ReadLine = Win7_Deployment) And (ObjExist_CorrectOU_7 = True))) Then
    WScript.Echo "IT WORKED!"
    'objShell.Run "JoinAD_Win7.vbs"
    Exit Do
  End If
  On Error Resume Next
Loop

f.Close
Set g = fso.OpenTextFile(filename)

Do While Not f.AtEndOfStream
  If ((g.ReadLine = Win10_Deployment) Or ((g.ReadLine = Win10_Deployment) And (ObjExist_CorrectOU_10 = True))) Then
    'objShell.Run "JoinAD_Win10.vbs"
    WScript.Echo "IT WORKED AGAIN!"
    Exit Do
  End If
  On Error Resume Next
Loop

g.Close

Set objShell = Nothing
```

The problem I'm running into is that the two `If..Then` statements execute every time, even though I know the conditions are absolutely NOT being met.

Does it have to do with my use of `Or` and `And`?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow; thank you for posting your first question. Please identify the specific statements you're talking about. It is helpful for new users to read the following: [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [The perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please consider editing your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question does not satisfy [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) criteria. 
However, *at first sight*: read [`On Error` Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53f3k80h(v=vs.84).aspx) and [`ReadLine` Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/skwz6sz4(v=vs.84).aspx) and [Working with Files](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/czxefwt8(v=vs.84).aspx) documentation.

```
Do While Not f.AtEndOfStream
  '''  ↓ this `ReadLine` reads every uneven line i.e. the 1st, 3rd, 5th, …
  If ((f.ReadLine = Win7_Deployment) Or ((f.ReadLine = Win7_Deployment) And (ObjExist_CorrectOU_7 = True))) Then
  '''      this one reads every even line ↑      i.e. the 2nd, 4th, 6th, …
    WScript.Echo "IT WORKED!"
    'objShell.Run "JoinAD_Win7.vbs"
    Exit Do
  End If
  On Error Resume Next ' this causes that script continues on line next to IF … THEN
                       ' in case of uneven records in file.
                       ' i.e. runtimme error "Input past end of file"
Loop
```

Use something like

```
Do While Not f.AtEndOfStream
  sReadLine = f.ReadLine
  If ((sReadLine = Win7_Deployment) Or ((sReadLine = Win7_Deployment) And (ObjExist_CorrectOU_7 = True))) Then
    WScript.Echo "IT WORKED!"
    'objShell.Run "JoinAD_Win7.vbs"
    Exit Do
  End If
  ''' get rid of `On Error Resume Next` statement at all
Loop
```

And what about `Do While Not f.AtEndOfStream` followed up by `g.ReadLine`? Use either `f` or `g` (the same [TextStream object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/314cz14s(v=vs.84).aspx) in both)…

Comment: First off, I would have to disagree with not meeting the code criteria. There may be a little bit too much code, thus not meeting the "minimal" aspect, but I needed it to show where variables were coming from. That is why I provided the wall of code. In the future, I'll try to refrain from doing so as it must have made it harder for you to answer. That being said, your answer makes a lot of sense. I obviously did not understand the meaning of f.ReadLine, but you've made that clear. Thank you. I will try your solution by assigning the f.ReadLine to a variable and check back in. Thanks again.